# order a new Gson().toJson() in Java

Tags: java, android, json, string, gson

This code use a Map with two `List<String>`
inside a `Map<String, List<?>>`
and I need to get an Output with this order **ttPrm,ttDet**  and what I get is **ttDet,ttPrm**.

this is my code

```
String parametroGSON ="";
try {
    Map<String, List<?>> mapa = new HashMap<String, List<?>>();
    mapa.put("ttPrm", listParam);
    mapa.put("ttDet", ListaArt);
    parametroGSON = new Gson().toJson(mapa);
} catch (Exception e) { }
System.out.println(json);
```

Output:

```
 {"ttDet":[{"dsArticulo":"PEPSI 500 X 12 PET"}],"ttPrm":[{"accion":"upd","cod_depo":"1"}]}
```

I need this output

```
{"ttPrm":[{"accion":"upd","cod_depo":"1"}] ,"ttDet":[{"dsArticulo":"PEPSI 500 X 12 PET"}]}
```

How can I do to get this output?  this new Gson().toJson(mapa); this order is alphabetical? can I have an arbitrary order?

Comment: your question has current and expected output one and the same

Comment: in the more detailed description the current and expected output are correct. - fixed question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at a first glance this seems to be the expected output. Due to the hashCode implementation in the String class ttDet precedes ttPrm as it has a smaller hashCode.

Using a LinkedHashMap may help. Try

```
String parametroGSON ="";
try {
  Map<String, List<?>> mapa = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<?>>();
  mapa.put("ttPrm", listParam);
  mapa.put("ttDet", ListaArt);
  parametroGSON = new Gson().toJson(mapa);
} catch (Exception e) { }
System.out.println(json);
```

instead.

Depending on the exact requirements another map may be useful, the LinkedHashMap keeps the insertion order (same as with the LinkedHashSet).